# Problem with Aggregating Households Extension after upgrade to 5.3.1

Tags: extension, upgrade, reports, households

I had this problem after another upgrade and can't figure out how I solved it! (Posted as an issue at github as well.)

Extension installed, Enabled | ver 1.2 and at /home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/civiextensions/me.twomice.civicrm.aggregatehouseholdcontributions

All existing reports error out with:

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Aggregatehouseholdcontributions/Report/Form/Contribute/AggregatedHouseholds.php' (include_path='/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/civiextensions/com.iatspayments.civicrm/:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/civiextensions/de.systopia.householdmerge-1.1.beta/:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/civiextensions/com.pogstone.fancytokens/:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/civiextensions/nz.co.fuzion.cssinline/:.:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/ in /home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php on line 451

A file by that name is at:
/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom/customphp/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/AggregatedHouseholds.php

Copying it to:
/home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/custom/customphp/CRM/Aggregatehouseholdcontributions/Report/Form/Contribute/AggregatedHouseholds.php
does NOT fix it.

The code referenced is
require_once str_replace('', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
in the snippet below

$ext = CRM_Extension_System::singleton()->getMapper();
      if ($ext->isExtensionClass($className)) {
        require_once $ext->classToPath($className);
      }
      else {
               require_once str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
      }

Comment: Got it working manually by adding the file here: /home/MYSITEDIR/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Aggregatehouseholdcontributions/Report/Form/Contribute/AggregatedHouseholds.php

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to add manually in CiviCRM module folder. The system should pick the file from custom php or extension. Looking initially at the debug you provided looks like the custom php path or extension path is not included. Here are few things i would try before making it work in a unusual way

1. Check directory path is set correctly.
2. Clean up CiviCRM caches
3. Uninstall/disbale and install/enable extension. (Note: If the extension is responsible to store data and uninstall would cause data loss than try disabling-enabling extension)
4. Check if existing extensions is conflicting any problem by disabling the extension and trying.